# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider error with @react-navigation/stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

When I am trying to use `import {createStackNavigator} from @react-navigation/stack`, it gives me an error

`Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider`

I have tried finding a solution, but nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: RNCSafeAreaProvider is related to this module: https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110 However, there might be a duplicate installation out there inside other modules such as:
https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/2721

Answer (score 53):

Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider error with @react-navigation/stack

It means you have installed same extension multiple times.

Running "npm dedupe" command solved my problem.

or Yarn install (The dedupe command isn’t necessary. yarn install will already dedupe.)

Comment: If you are using yarn, it says: error The dedupe command isn't necessary. `yarn install` will already dedupe.

Comment: `npm deduce` fixed my issue

Comment: i use yarn install and it doesn't work. but npm dedupe works

Comment: this worked to get me running on Android, but IOS still doesn't work... so weird! Thanks doe!

Answer (score 19):

For my case, two different `masked-view` packages in `package.json` caused it:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.4",
```

ReactNavigation5 [requires](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/masked-view/) `@react-native-community/masked-view`, while [`react-native-skeleton-placeholder`](https://github.com/chramos/react-native-skeleton-placeholder) has the other as the prerequisite. So, watching your dependencies, you can remove one of those to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 15):

Just running

```sh
expo upgrade
```

solved my issue.

Comment: Editor's note: do not rollback or override edits from community members that improve formatting and/or syntax and spelling. In your case, the user fixed formatting misuse. Code blocks should not be formatted as quotes, much less as nested quotes.

Comment: I ran into this problem when I upgraded my project using npm-check-updates. That is obviously not the correct way of doing it for Expo projects. Now using `expo upgrade` all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

reinstalling `react-native-safe-area-context` did the trick for me in EXPO.

Comment: This works for me too

Answer (score 8):

There have been few fixes on Github for [this package issues](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110#issuecomment-668864576) on resolving the above dreadful error, which one of it happens to work for me. I'll highlight a couple of fixes here and follow the link for more.

Follow these steps to fix it, but I only tried the last part:

- delete node_modules and your lock file (package-lock.json / yarn.lock)
- change the expo package version in package.json to 38.0.8
- remove react-native-safe-area-context from your package.json
- run `yarn or npm install`

> The below step works for me.

- run `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

Thanks to `brentvatne`.

Comment: the line that helped me: `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

Comment: I'd very much recommend you not delete your lock file. That can cause major issues with your application far beyond what they may or may not fix.

Answer (score 4):

package.json adding in scripts `npm dedupe` worked for me .

Comment: This appears to be simply confirming that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66999488/10871073) worked. That means it is not an answer, of itself, and shouldn't be posted as one.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I forgot to add one line which is `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` on top of the file in **index.js**

if you don't install it so you have to install it first by using the command
`npm install react-native-gesture-handler`

OR

`yarn add react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: When I upgraded react-navigation from 3-4 I forgot to include this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Even though its already answered I'll provide a solution that worked for me.

"react-native-safe-area-context" is probably causing a conflict with Navigation Container.

Removing "safe-area-context" solved the issue temporarily for me and its probably the way for a more permanent solution.

Im a React-Native beginner but this is my input to help other people with similar issues.

Comment: This was the exact issue I was facing. Now, according to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area, react-native-safe-area-context is required to support navigation.

This is what I did to solve mine:
1. deleted 'react-native-safe-area-context' from my 'package.json' 
2. ran 'yarn' 
3. ran 'expo install react-native-safe-area-context' . This will ensure that expo adds this package itself, since the conflict was btw 'expo' and 'react-native'

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with react-native-safe-area-context.
So I searched for it in my yarn.lock and found out that some other lib was using a different version of safe-area-context than the one I had in my package.json

[react-native-gifted-chat was using version 4.2.4 of react-native-safe-area-context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2xqv.png)

[I had version 3.3.2 in my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66E2.png)

So I updated my package.json to use the same version (4.2.4) and it worked

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was uninstalling react-native-elements and reinstalling them.

react-native-safe-area-context has a module inside of react-native-elements, which caused caused the duplicate error.

The other answers worked only temporarily but the error would continue to appear

Answer (score 2):

it works for me version sdk(42.0.0) ❤️❤️❤️

here is the solution :)

open your app route folder ==> node_modules ==> invariant ==> browser.js

**in browser.js file remove the  [if condition code] (line number 28 to 46 )**

my package.json file given below :

"expo": "~42.0.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",

"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",

Answer (score 2):

it works for me version SDK(42.0.0)

here is the solution :)

open your app route folder ==> node_modules ==> invariant ==> browser.js

in browser.js file remove the [if condition code] (line number 28 to 46 )

my package.json file given below :

```
"expo": "~42.0.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",

"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.5.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pack-lock.json file, remove the `react-native-safe-area-context`. That will solve the problem.

The code will look like this:

```html
  "react-native-elements": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-elements/-/react-native-elements-3.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-U4CuyO+q2JlduPht4P0xz+oIbw3W53uYPpkMqvlwjJiVoFfwnpbAu+JZL01/7VMe98G4Y8nJImcBh7zK9cb3Uw==",
      "requires": {
        "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
        "color": "^3.1.2",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
        "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
        "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react-native-ratings": "^7.3.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
        "react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "deepmerge": {
          "version": "4.2.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deepmerge/-/deepmerge-4.2.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-FJ3UgI4gIl+PHZm53knsuSFpE+nESMr7M4v9QcgB7S63Kj/6WqMiFQJpBBYz1Pt+66bZpP3Q7Lye0Oo9MPKEdg=="
        },
        "opencollective-postinstall": {
          "version": "2.0.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/opencollective-postinstall/-/opencollective-postinstall-2.0.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-8AV/sCtuzUeTo8gQK5qDZzARrulB3egtLzFgteqB2tcT4Mw7B8Kt7JcDHmltjz6FOAHsvTevk70gZEbhM4ZS9Q=="
        },
        ---> "react-native-safe-area-context": { <--- remove this
          "version": "3.1.9",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-safe-area-context/-/react-native-safe-area-context-3.1.9.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-wmcGbdyE/vBSL5IjDPReoJUEqxkZsywZw5gPwsVUV1NBpw5eTIdnL6Y0uNKHE25Z661moxPHQz6kwAkYQyorxA=="
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked using the commands:

```
npm dedupe
expo update
```

Comment: `npm dedupe` was enough for me

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this might seem a little wacky hacky, and I'm not quite sure how or why it worked, but it did. I tried pretty much all the answers here and got nowhere.

*Note: I had `./package.json` in my directory already from when my app previously threw this error, see below*

For some reason, if do the following:

1. I run `Yarn`, allow it to create `./yarn.lock` and `./node_modules`
2. THEN I run `npm i` which creates the `./package-lock.json` file
3. Run `expo start`, my app loads...

I don't think this is good practice but it worked for me. Here's my `./package.json` which I had in my directory BEFORE I ran `yarn`/went through the steps in the order above:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.2.5",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If it works for anyone that visits, cool, if someone could explain or attempt to repeat this and comes up with an explanation please share.

Answer (score 0):

is here is the solution

Comented the line

open your app route folder ==> node_modules ==> invariant ==> browser.js

in browser.js file remove the [if condition code] (line number 28 to 46 )

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`
2. Run `yarn install` or `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears if you move your navigation and screens across files.

You can solve this by just running the command below if you are using expo or its equivalent it bare React Native app.

```
expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

[This github issue comment](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/2251#issuecomment-1343565831) helped me.
Basically, in my `package.json` I just went to the `react-native-safe-area-context` dependency, and changed my version `4.6.3` to `^4.6.3` and ran `yarn`/`npm install` again, and re-ran the project. Instant success.

Answer (score -2):

step 1: delete your node modules
Step 2: install node modules using yarn instead of npm install

Now,your issue Fixed