# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat, react-native-safe-area-view

I am getting this error when trying to import and use the GiftedChat component from "react-native-gifted-chat":

`Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider, js engine: hermes`

I have tried several things listed [here](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110#issuecomment-668864576). People appear to have similar issues with other packages relating to "react-native-safe-area-context".

- I have updated "react-native-safe-area-context" (4.2.5 at the time of this post)
- uninstalled "react-native-safe-area-context"

  - rm node_modules
  - rm -rf ios/Pods && ios/Podfile.lock
  - rm package-lock.json
  - npm install
  - reinstall pods -> npx pod-install
  - build the project again to the same error

I am NOT using expo but I am using the React Native CLI.

It appears to me that the issue is with "react-native-gifted-chat".

Details:

- "react-native": "0.66.4"
- "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9"
- "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.0"

If anyone has any ideas or insight I would appreciate it. If I find a solution I will post it as a comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931250/invariant-violation-tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rncsafeareap) post the error means the same extension is installed multiple times.

checked where "react-native-safe-area-view" was being used

`npm list react-native-safe-area-context`

Results:

```
├─┬ @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.1
│ ├─┬ @react-navigation/elements@1.3.3
│ │ └── react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9 deduped
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9 deduped
├─┬ @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9 deduped
├─┬ react-native-gifted-chat@1.0.0
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
└── react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9
```

it appears that gifted chat is pulling in 4.2.4 and 3.1.9

updated "react-native-safe-area-context" to latest version (4.2.5)

ran `npm dedupe`

"react-native-gifted-chat" appeared to still be pulling in two versions

```
├─┬ @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.1
│ ├─┬ @react-navigation/elements@1.3.3
│ │ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5 deduped
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5 deduped
├─┬ @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5 deduped
├─┬ react-native-gifted-chat@1.0.0
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
└── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5
```

This seemed odd so I check the package itself in node_modules`node_modules/node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/package.json` and found that the dependencies requested 4.2.4 specifically

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "3.13.0",
    "dayjs": "1.8.26",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-native-communications": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "1.3.1",
    "react-native-lightbox-v2": "0.9.0",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.22",
    --> "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4", <--
    "react-native-typing-animation": "0.1.7",
    "use-memo-one": "1.1.1",
    "uuid": "3.4.0"
  },
```

instead of requiring ^4.2.4 they specifically require version 4.2.4

---

side note:
**^** character defines a range of acceptable versions that include all patch and minor versions from the ones specified up to, but not including, the next version. So "^1.2.3" can be approximately expanded as ">=1.2.3 <2.0.0".

---

What does mean?

I installed the required version for "react-native-gifted-chat" which will work with all other dependencies then checked if it was finally deduped.

`npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4`

`npm list react-native-safe-area-context`

finally deduped

```
├─┬ @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.1
│ ├─┬ @react-navigation/elements@1.3.3
│ │ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4 deduped
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4 deduped
├─┬ @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4 deduped
├─┬ react-native-gifted-chat@1.0.0
│ └── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4 deduped
└── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
```

Error fixed.

Don't forget to reinstall your pods.

---

**TL;DR**

- "react-native-gifted-chat" did not write their package.json correctly.
- They **specifically** require version 4.2.4 of "react-native-safe-area-context"
- They should require versions ^4.2.4 (>=4.2.4 < 5.0.0)
- Installing this specific version fixes the issue since there is not two version of the package being used. `npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4`
- Could alternatively do a patch for "react-native-gifted-chat" making the fix just listed
- Don't forget to reinstall your pods and all that jazz

---

Comment: Well, the latest version react-native-gifted-chat@^1.0.4 pulls in the latest react-native-safe-area-context "^4.2.4" which is 4.3.3, but the latest Expo is looking for 4.3.1, so now I have trouble again with 2 versions.

Answer (score 2):

For me its working fine after upgrading react-native-safe-area-context to version 4.3.3

```
npm i react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.3
```

Comment: I did the same thing. As suggest by the other answer, you need to make sure that only 1 version shows up when you run: `npm list react-native-safe-area-context`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (when dealing with react native gifted chat) and here's what I did:

1. `npm depude`
2. `npm ls react-native-safe-area-context`

and if you have more than one version run the following `npm i react-native-safe-area-context@<the oldest one>`

3. delete `node_modules`
4. `run npm i`