# React Native Expo - Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider

Tags: react-native, expo

After upgratding to `Expo SDK 49` I am getting this error

> "Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider, js engine: hermes site:stackoverflow.com"

I have tried with install & uninstall `react-native-safe-area-context`. I have also tried with deleting `node_modules` & `package-lock.json` & then `npm install`. But still the issue is not getting resolved. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider error with @react-navigation/stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931250/invariant-violation-tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rncsafeareap)

Comment: try this: npx expo install --fix