# ERROR Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCViewPager, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

so i want to make something similar to instagram profile screen where up you have the info and down you have the "tabview" which contains various content options (posts/shorts...)

i have the `<SectionList>`

```js
            <SectionList
                sections={sections}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View style={styles.shortsList}>
                        <ProfileShortItem short={item} />
                    </View>
                )}
                renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
                    <View>
                        {title()}
                    </View>
                )}
                removeClippedSubviews
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                shouldRasterizeIOS
                stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
            />
```

and my sections:

```js
const sections = [
        {
            title: () => (
                <View style={{ ...styles.container, paddingTop: insets.top * 2 }}>
                    <View style={styles.profileBox}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.profileImage}
                            source={{ uri: user.photoURL }}
                        />
                        {user.fullName ?
                            <Title weight="regular" size="medium">{user.fullName}</Title>
                            :
                            <Title weight="regular" size="medium" color="secondary">
                                add your name
                                <Feather name="edit-3" size={16} color={colors.textInDarkGray} />
                            </Title>
                        }
                    </View>

                    <ProfileActionButtons user={user} />
                </View>
            ),
            data: () => (
                <ProfileTabs userShorts={userShorts} />
            )
        }
    ];
```

finally the ProfileTabs:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
import { SceneMap, TabBar, TabView } from "react-native-tab-view";

// other imports...

type Props = {
    userShorts: IShort[];
}

const ProfileTabs = (props: Props) => {
    const layout = useWindowDimensions();

    const ShortsRoute = () => {
        if (props.userShorts.length) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: layout.height }}>
                    <ShortsList shorts={props.userShorts} />
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
                    <Title align="center">Nothing to see :(</Title>
                </View>
            )
        }
    };

    const OthersRoute = () => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#4008a9' }} />
    );

    const renderScene = SceneMap({
        shorts: ShortsRoute,
        others: OthersRoute,
    });

    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const [routes] = React.useState([
        { key: 'shorts', title: 'Shorts' },
        { key: 'others', title: 'Others' },
    ]);

    const renderTabBar = (props: any) => (
        // tab bar options...
    )

    return (
        <TabView
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
            renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
        />
    );
};

export default ProfileTabs;
```

and for some reason I get the `Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCViewPager` error

can you please help me solve this issue? thanks in advance

EDIT: this is what my dependencies are:

```
"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.16",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.1.0",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.11",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-gl": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-screen-capture": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-store-review": "~6.4.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.17",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~7.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.3.1",
    "hono": "^3.5.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moti": "^0.27.0",
    "onesignal-expo-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.9.0-alpha.21",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-virtualized-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "stream-chat-expo": "^5.17.1",
    "throttle-debounce": "^5.0.0"
```

Comment: Please add the dependencies list from the `package.json`

Comment: added, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931250/invariant-violation-tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rncsafeareap ?

Comment: yes, before asking i always try to find the solution, thats why im asking